# Add react icon(s) dynamically to navbar item(s) in component

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap, react-icons

Bear with me, I'm learning React so I'm a beginner. I'm trying to create a bottom navigation panel. Rather than hardcoding each navbar element, I have found good examples of storing navbar elements in an array then mapping that onto your navbar. I have gotten the below to work, except I'm not sure how to dynamically reference the icon in my navTabs array within the component itself? I can add (for example) `<FaIdCard />` without issue, but I don't want to have to hard code this as it would defeat the point of generating the navigation from the array.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, NavItem} from 'reactstrap';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FaIdCard, FaInfoCircle } from "react-icons/fa";


/* This array will be mapped onto our nav elements */
const navTabs = [{
    route: "/about",
    icon: FaInfoCircle,
    label: "About"
},{
    route: "/customer",
    icon: FaIdCard,
    label: "Customer"      
}]

const Navigation = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light" role="navigation">
                <Nav className="w-100">
                    <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around w-100">
                        { 
                        /*  index is a built-in part of .map that gives u index number. 
                            The grave accent (`) is used for template literals, or combining variables, javascript and text/html
                        */
                            navTabs.map((tab, index) =>(
                                <NavItem key={`tab-${index}`}> 
                                    <NavLink to={tab.route} className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">
                                        <div className="row d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                            <div>{tab.label}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </NavLink>
                                </NavItem>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                </Nav>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
  };
  
  export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the icon components for your `icon` property:

```
const navTabs = [{
    route: "/about",
    icon: <FaInfoCircle />,
    label: "About"
},{
    route: "/customer",
    icon: <FaIdCard />,
    label: "Customer"      
}]
```

Then add it to the `NavItem` like this:

```
<NavItem key={`tab-${index}`}>
  <NavLink to={tab.route} className='nav-link' activeClassName='active'>
    <div className='row d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>
      <div>
        {tab.icon} {tab.label}
      </div>
    </div>
  </NavLink>
</NavItem>;
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Working with typescript, this worked for me instead:

```
// type
import { IconType } from "react-icons";

export type NavTabsType = {
  route: string;
  icon?: IconType;
  label: string;
};


// navTabs array
const navTabs = [
    {
        route: "/about",
        icon:  FaInfoCircle,
        label: "About"
    },
    ...
];


// component
...

<div>
    {tab.icon && <tab.icon />} {tab.label}
</div>

...
```

Don't forget to import all that needs to be imported.